# function used from within javascript dojo closure using "this"-notation is undefined

Tags: javascript, dojo, closures, this

I have a Problem accessing an Object function using "this".
In case of the below example (which is simplified, because I cannot supply actual code due to various reasons) the function call this._getEntry() is "undefined" when calling
createList().

I would hope for some opinions on wether this is due to a misunderstanding of
javascript closures or rather a syntax error.

In the latter case I will have to find the error in the actual code myself.

If it is a misunderstanding of javascript or dojo concepts I would really appreciate
some help on how to correctly scope and access the below mentioned function (_getEntry()).

```
var OBJECT = {
  _getEntry : function(entry){
    var li = document.createElement('LI');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry));
    return li;
  },
  createList : function(entryArray){
    var list = document.createElement('UL');
    dojo.forEach(entryArray,function(entry){
      list.appendChild(this._getEntry(entry));
    });
    dojo.body().appendChild(list);
  }
};
OBJECT.createList(["entry1","entry2"]);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I think your pasted code is missing `);` to complete the `forEach`.

Secondly, `forEach` takes an optional third parameter which determines the context in which the passed function runs.  If not given, it defaults to the global scope, so yes this is your problem.  Assuming `this` already refers to what you need it to immediately outside the `forEach`, you should be able to just pass `this` in as the third argument to `forEach` and it should work, e.g.:

```
dojo.forEach(entryArray, function(entry){
  list.appendChild(this._getEntry(entry));
}, this);
```

For more information: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/forEach - which is based on the API in JS 1.6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem and you are right, its all about scoping and closure. What is happening here is once you get into the `forEach` the context changes to the global context (`window`). Handily, Dojo provides a way to set this context:

```
  createList : function(entryArray){
    var list = document.createElement('UL');
    dojo.forEach(entryArray,function(entry){
      list.appendChild(this._getEntry(entry));
    }, this);

    dojo.body().appendChild(list);
  }
```

An alternate approach is to use closure to get at `this`

```
  createList : function(entryArray){
    var list = document.createElement('UL');
    var _this = this; // closure allowing the forEach callback access to this
                      // some popular variable names used for this include:
                      // $this, _this, me and that
    dojo.forEach(entryArray,function(entry){
      list.appendChild(_this._getEntry(entry));
    });

    dojo.body().appendChild(list);
  }
```

Comment: The context defaults to the global object if not provided explicitly as the third parameter to `dojo.forEach` - which would be another way around this.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for dojo and didn't see the parameter. Should have looked closer... I'll update